# Changing the app start-up window's colour

Tags: android, colors, startup, android-theme

I'd like to change the colour that flickers for a moment as an app is launching. I think it's determined by the overarching application theme, but I'd like to specify another colour.

To elaborate, I wouldn't like to modify the default  background colour for all activities, specified by:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
```

What's the most elegant way of achieving this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you need that screen then its ok, but if you really dont need that screen then you can remove it also.

Comment: I'm fine with keeping it, but that's nice to know

Answer (score 10):

In `/res/values` directory, modify your `styles.xml` file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now go to AndroidManifest.xml, and add the style to your activity launcher:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

I saw [a post of Google+](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/VVpjo7KDx4H) awhile ago. According to it, you can change the startup windows color by specifying it in your Theme.

> On app launch, Android displays a simple preview window (based on your
>   activity theme) as an immediate response to the user action. Then the
>   preview window crossfades with your actual UI, once that has fully
>   loaded. To ensure a smooth visual transition, your activity theme
>   should match your full UI as closely as possible. The below image
>   shows how the experience can be jarring if not handled properly.
>
> For example, if your activity does not require an action bar, then
>   disable it in your theme so that it doesn’t briefly appear in the
>   preview window. To do this, use or extend an activity theme with no
>   action bar. You can also override the background color of the window,
>   if applicable, to better match your full UI.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm avoiding that! I want to have a _different_ colour displayed on startup to the `android:windowBackground` colour.